# Trigger email firebase extension permission error

Tags: firebase

I've previously successfully configured trigger email extension and wanted to reuse it in another project i'm working with. The problem I have is that I receive a permission error and i'm not sure what to do with it.

Data is added correctly into database

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("messages").add({
    from: "My email <myemail@gmail.com>",
    to: "myemail@gmail.com",
    replyTo: "My email<myemail@gmail.com>",
    message: {
        subject: subject,
        text: body
    }
})
```

Which triggers the processQueue function which is part of trigger email extension.

```
Unhandled error occurred during processing: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:195:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
for call at
at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:163:34)
at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:225:29
at /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
at repeat (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
at /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:118:13
at OngoingCallPromise.call (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
at NormalApiCaller.call (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
at /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30 {
code: 7,
details: 'Missing or insufficient permissions.',
metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

Firestore permissions are currently set to allow everything.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /messages/{message} {
    allow read, write: if true;
  }
}
}
```

What else may cause the permission denied error?

Comment: FYI since the Extension is based on a Cloud Function you don’t need to open the write and read access to the `messages` collection: The admin SDK bypasses the security rules. So it is recommended to deny any access in such a way malicious users cannot send emails by creating documents.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be an issue with the deployment process. Re-installing the extension resolved the issue.